# how to count number of sub array in lua string

Tags: lua

how to count number of sub array in lua string.

I have a lua string in following format,

> {{"engName1":"Test1","validDurPeriod":0,"appStatus":2,"engName3":"",
>   "ExtraInfo":{"returnPeriod":7,"stayType":50,"fingerprintInd":49,"stayPeriod":6,"medicalInd":49},}
>   {"engName1":"Test2","validDurPeriod":3,"appStatus":2,"engName3":"", },
>   {"engName1":"Test3","validDurPeriod":2,"appStatus":2,"engName3":"","ExtraInfo":{"returnPeriod":7,"stayType":50,"fingerprintInd":49,"stayPeriod":6,"medicalInd":49}
>   }, {"engName1":"Test4","validDurPeriod":3,"appStatus":2,"engName3":"",
>   },}

I want to count number of sub arrays in lua string ,
something like {{},{},{},{}} as here count is 4

I tried something below code to check its contains array but not able to get the exact count.
below code is working for single array but not working for multiple array

```
function checkType(sample)

if string.startswith(sample, "{{", true) or string.startswith(sample, "{ {", true)  or string.startswith(sample, "{  {", true) then
 return true;
else
return false;
end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at JSON libraries?

Comment: Why do you need to count these? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table works correctly, you should be able to use the function table.getn(table).

Examples:

```
print(table.getn{10,2,4})          --> 3
print(table.getn{10,2,nil})        --> 2
print(table.getn{n=1000})          --> 1000

a = {}
print(table.getn(a))               --> 0
```

I hope that does the trick ;)

Source: [19.1 - Array Size](http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html)

Comment: wouldn't just `#a` be better, also because of forward compatibility to 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

If `s` contains your string, then `n` below contains the count:

```
local _,n=s:gsub("[^{}]",""):gsub("{}","")
```

Comment: Why do you need to count these? Depending on number of elements found in string I need to run a for loop and display these values.